# do p4 edit for multiple files which contain a matching pattern

Tags: bash, shell, perforce

I have few files inside a folder. But some of the files contain a particular pattern inside them. I want to grep those files and do p4 edit on those files.

I have used this command on my terminal, but it doesnt work.

```
grep -rl "pattern" * | p4 edit
```

Note: I am inside the folder in which all the files reside.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass the output of grep to `xargs`

```
grep -rl "pattern" * | xargs p4 edit
```

Comment: Thanks . It works. If i want to pipeline this command with another command as this `grep -rl "pattern" * | xargs p4 edit | xargs sed -i 's/pattern/replace_word/g'` ... then it doesnot work.. any solution for it...

Comment: if you want to edit it through sed means why you pass the grep output to `p4`, just pass directly to sed like `grep -rl "pattern" * | xargs sed -i 's/pattern/replace_word/g'`

Comment: i want to do it because my goal is to search the files and open them in p4 edit mode. then replace. then do the checkin. And they asked me to find out any one line command for this...

Comment: I suggest posting a new question that describes the full task you're trying to accomplish from start to finish, including what "pattern" and "replace_word" are if possible.  What you're describing so far sounds suspiciously like it boils down to simply "rename a folder" -- if so there are MUCH easier ways to do this.  :)

Answer (score 3):

The normal way to do this is to do:

```
grep -rl "pattern" * | p4 -x - edit
```

`p4 help usage` explains `-x`:

> The -x flag instructs p4 to read the arguments, one per line, from the specified file.  If you specify '-', standard input is read.

Answer (score 2):

I think this information is might useful to someone. First run following command to open all files.

```
p4 edit ...
```

Make your changes and run following command to revert the files which are not modified.

```
p4 revert -a
```